# Which sunni scholars denied ijma'?

Tags: sunni, islamic-scholar, usool-ul-fiqh

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mu2gRxQNLbk), Adnan Ibrahim argues against Ijma'. He also quotes Imam Ahmed:

> "قال " من ادَّعى الإجماع فقد كذب ، وما يدريه لعل الناس اختلفوا
>   Imam Ahmed said: "The one calling upon ijma' has lied!"

The same quote is found [here](https://saaid.net/Doat/ehsan/63.htm), more context of it:

> والإجماع إجماعان ، إجماع ظني وإجماع قطعي ، والأول هو الذي يثبت بالبحث والتحري عن أقوال الأئمة ، ويحتاج من مثبته إلى استقراء لكتب الخلاف ، وهو الذي أنكره الإمام أحمد وقال " من ادَّعى الإجماع فقد كذب ، وما يدريه لعل الناس اختلفوا " .

In this [video](https://youtu.be/ps7bdeKDwjU?t=52m50s), he denies ijma' to be a part of his methods of usul al fiqh.

**Which sunni scholars denied ijma' as a method among the methods in usul al fiqh?**
*This question is of course based on another question, did any sunni scholars really deny ijma?*

---

*Disclaimer: I am not supposing these quotes are proofs too deny ijma', rather it seems some have used them when aruging against ijma'. I know they are possible to be interpreted in another way in its context. Also, it seems to be different interpretations of what exactly is ijma'. And the person denying ijma' isn't necessary denying the matters as five prayers a day and such.*

Comment: I assume the quotes are taken out of context. I only wonder if there's am existing example of an ijma' where there's no text (quran/sunnah).

Comment: @Medi1Saif If you got time to answer sometime and clarify that would be great! Also I understand that all the madhabs has ijma as a method in usul al fiqh, so **if** some scholars really denied ijma, i guess they ain't many.

Comment: You may have realized that my answers lately are rather short and often incomplete (because of lack of time). And this comment only reflects my impression and a question i have in mind since i started reading about the dispute about ijma' and the differences about majorities when it comes to fatwas and opinions. I don't feel like having the time to investigate at the moment.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I see! If you do get time in the near future I'd appreciate a (well written) answer from you (as usual)!

Comment: Of note, there are different opinions of what *ijma* even is and how/when to apply it (see related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/441/22). So it's probable that most scholars did deny *certain forms* of *ijma* while accepting others, rather than the whole concept of *ijma* itself.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by ijma' that was denied or accepted by Sunni scholars. There are at least six definitions of ijma' in terms of its two components: the people involved, and the criterion used for acceptance of consensus. The quotes you provided and the ones in the video are responses to specific definitions of ijma', not ijma' at large.

Comment: Based on the quotes you may generate a long list of scholars whom denied a type or any types if ijma' after the time of sahaba. Because this is the missing context of those quotes.

Comment: @Medi1Saif — Actually Ibn Hanbal's quote is chopped and out of context. It was mentioned by his son 'Abdullah in relation to Bushr Al-Marrisi and Abu Bakr Al-Assam in specific. Al-Shafi'i's quote is about what constitutes ijma', rather than denying it. Without an understanding of what the specific definition being asked about, it will be difficult to answer in context.

Comment: @III-AK-III See my edit "Disclaimer". Also I changed the question a bit: "Which sunni scholars denied ijma' as a method among the methods in usul al fiqh?" As Adnan Ibrahim stated in a video, he denied ijma as a method in usul al fiqh at all

Comment: @III-AK-III I edited the question again and added this [video](https://youtu.be/ps7bdeKDwjU?t=52m50s)

Comment: @Kilise — Thanks. The second video will take time to watch and understand. From the few minutes that I watched, I can see that the argument is similar to that of [Al-Judai'](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/عبد_الله_بن_يوسف_الجديع) and [Al-Qaradawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yusuf_al-Qaradawi). This is not to say that the question is easy to answer :-), but at least the views on this specific definition can be discussed: ijma' is when the first three generations all agree on the same ruling.

Answer (score -1):

In this playlist you will find many evidences from Quran, Hadith, Companions and those who came after the companions who have rejected Ijma'.  Ijma' in it's current form is a man made principles, used by people to patch the religion of Allah swt.  This playlist clarifies everything: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdgHrXZm8HpNFEIkSu3QToTvGGPVp1-cc